# spring boot setContentType is not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, content-type

I'm trying to return an image on spring-boot (1.2.2)
How should I set the content-type?
Non of the following are working for me (meaning that response headers are not containing 'content-type' header at all ):

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/files2/{file_name:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getFile2(final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = //someInputStream...
    org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    InputStreamResource inputStreamR = new InputStreamResource(is);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(inputStreamR, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/files3/{file_name:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity<byte[]> getFile3() throws IOException {
    InputStream is = //someInputStream...
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
    return new HttpEntity<>(IOUtils.toByteArray(is), headers);
}
```

Comment: Pleas define "not working".

Comment: @ci_ I mean that response headers are not containing 'content-type' header at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it... Had to add `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter` to `WebConfiguration` class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> httpMessageConverters) {
    httpMessageConverters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
}
}
```

And the then my second attempt (`getFile3()`) was working correctly

Comment: Great.. perhaps it's due to different SpringBoot versions (we're using 1.2.3), but using `produces` did not require registration of the additional byte array converter.. it just works.

Comment: @tombola82 I think its because of the `@Configuration` annotation which overrides a lot of default settings for spring. Before I added `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter`  I could also make this work by remove the `@Configuration` annotation ...

Comment: hmm.. I'm not totally convinced by that ;-)  we also use `@Configuration` on config classes (in conjunction with `@SpringBootApplication` which in turn enables auto config and _that_ provides a lot of default config) - still no byte array message converter present.. and it 'just works'. `@Configuration` is not a spring-boot annotation, only spring framework for java config.  But you have a solution so that's the most important thing!

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, you'll need to apply the `@ResponseBody` annotation in addition to `@RequestMapping`, unless you are using `@RestController` at the class level instead of just `@Controller`. Also, try the `produces` element of `@RequestMapping` e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files2/{file_name:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE})
```

This should 'narrow the primary mapping' and ensure the correct content type is set.  See the docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-produces

Comment: I can only do this `produces = "image/jpeg"` but results are the same (response headers are not containing 'content-type' header at all), plus I think this is just for `narrow the primary mapping` and *NOT to* `ensure the correct content type is set`

Comment: Just corrected the MediaType value in produces - should have been the string version as you point out. As far as I can tell and from just trying it myself, that should work - even without `@ResponseBody` as you're returning an entity.. have you taken out the code to set the content-type header manually? Incidentally I used your second attempted solution (with `HttpEntity<byte[]>` to test this)

Comment: on your second point - the doc states: _"Furthermore, use of the produces condition ensures the actual content type used to generate the response respects the media types specified in the produces condition"_.  That is how it works for me anyway - if I take out the `produces` element I just get `text/html` default content-type.